# Uploading with Google Drive SDK

Tags: c#, google-drive-api

Getting request.ResponseBody = null when trying to upload to my drive. 
I'm seeign the following exception 'Value cannot be null.Parameter name: baseUri'

here's the code

```
                Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File body = new Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File();
                body.Title = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(uploadFile);
                body.Description = "File uploaded";
                body.MimeType = GetMimeType(uploadFile);
                body.Editable = true;
                body.Shared = false;
                body.Parents = new List<ParentReference>() { new ParentReference() { Id = parentID } };

                var x = service.HttpClient.GetByteArrayAsync(uploadFile);
                byte[] arrBytes = x.Result;
                System.IO.MemoryStream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(arrBytes);


 try
                {
                    if (arrBytes.Length > 0)
                    {
                        FilesResource.InsertMediaUpload request = service.Files.Insert(body, stream, GetMimeType(uploadFile));
                        request.Convert = true;
                        request.Upload();
                        return request.ResponseBody;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("File does not exist: " + uploadFile);
                        return null;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("An error occurred: " + e.Message);
                    return null;
                }
```

any ideas on what I'm missing ?

**EDIT**

The file uploads to the drive now , I removed any Referrers in the API section.
but the response is still null

Comment: These SO would help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23156369/youtube-upload-file-give-me-argumentnullexception-c and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26204080/big-query-exception-is-value-cannot-be-null-parameter-name-baseuri

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem  – After updating via nuget - Zlib.Portable is updated to version 1.11.0.0, while Google is using version 1.10.0.0  -
check your references versions!

Comment: I don't think this is the cause of his problem zlib 1.11 was only just released this week.   I am not sure why it would fix your problem but I am glad that it did.

Comment: I didn't write - this is the cause (that what happen to me) - I wrote  - need to check references...